# Is $SL_n (R)$ residually finite when $R$ is a polynomial ring over a finite field

Tags: group-theory

Let $\mathbb{F}_q$ be a finite field and let $R=\mathbb{F}_q [t]$ be the polynomial ring over that field. For $n \geq 3$ denote $G=SL_n (R)$ to be the special linear group over the ring $R$. My question is: is $G$ residually finite, i.e., is there a sequence of normal finite index subgroups $\lbrace N_i \rbrace_{i=1}^\infty$ such that $\bigcap N_i = \lbrace e \rbrace$?

My guess is that the answer is yes due to the following reasoning: take $I_i = <t^i >$ to be the ideal in $R$ generated by $t^i$ and let $\phi_i : G \rightarrow SL_n (R/I_i)$ to be the homomorpism that sends each matrix entry to its quotient, then for every $i \in \mathbb{N}$, $N_i = ker (\phi_i)$ is a finite index normal subgroup of $G$. I think that the intersection of the $N_i$'s should be trivial, but I haven't been able to show that.

Comment: A polynomial of degree $n$ cannot be a multiple of $t^{n+1}$. Polynomials over integral domains satisfy $\deg(fg) = \deg(f) + \deg(g)$.

Comment: of course - how trivial.